# Scala: Breaking out of foldLeft

Tags: scala

Suppose we have Seq `val ourSeq = Seq(10,5,3,5,4)`.

I want to return a new list which reads from the left and stop when it sees a duplicate number (e.g. `Seq(10,5,3)` since 5 is repeated).

I was thinking of using fold left as such

```scala
ourSeq.foldLeft(Seq())(op = (temp, curr) => {

  if (!temp.contains(curr)) {
    temp :+ curr 
  } else break

})
```

but as far as I understand, there is no way to break out of a `foldLeft`?

Comment: Do not use a **Seq** but rather a **List** and write your own tail recursive solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it's not possible to break out of `foldLeft`. It would theoretically be possible to get the correct result with `foldLeft`, but you're still going to iterate the whole data structure. It'll be better to use an algorithm that already understands how to terminate early, and since you want to take a prefix, [`takeWhile`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#takeWhile(p:A=%3EBoolean):C) will suffice.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Set

val ourSeq = Seq(10, 5, 3, 5, 4)

val seen: Set[Int] = Set()
val untilDups = ourSeq.takeWhile((x) => {
  if (seen contains x) {
    false
  } else {
    seen += x
    true
  }
})
print(untilDups)
```

If you wanted to be totally immutable about this, you could wrap the whole thing in some kind of lazy fold that uses an immutable `Set` to keep its data. And that's certainly how I'd do it in Haskell. But this is Scala; we have mutability, and we may as well use it locally when it suits us.

Answer (score 4):

Although it *can* be accomplished with a `foldLeft()` *without* any breaking out, I would argue that `fold` is the wrong tool for the job.

I'm rather fond of `unfold()`, which was introduced in Scala 2.13.0.

```
val ourSeq = Seq(10,5,3,5,4)
Seq.unfold((Set.empty[Int],ourSeq)){ case (seen,ns) =>
  Option.when(ns.nonEmpty && !seen(ns.head)) {
    (ns.head, (seen+ns.head, ns.tail))
  }
}
//res0: Seq[Int] = Seq(10, 5, 3)
```

Comment: Nifty but I think `takeWhile` is a more intuitive approach, it does exactly what it says. `unfold` reads like the opposite of `fold`, and normally I’d use it to expand one value into many. Like “given an integer n, generate all integers from 1 whose cumulative sum is less than n” would be a good choice for `unfold` IMO.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar; More intuitive, perhaps, but more verbose and requires a mutable `Set` (not in keeping with FP principles). But, hey, they both get the job done.

Comment: Scala ain’t Haskell. Mutable collections are there for times when we need them. But yes, more than one ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a recursive function:

```
def uniquePrefix[T](ourSeq: Seq[T]): List[T] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(rem: List[T], res: List[T]): List[T] = 
    rem match {
      case hd::tail if !res.contains(hd) =>
        loop(tail, res :+ hd)
      case _ =>
        res
    }

  loop(ourSeq.toList, Nil)
}
```

This appears more complicated, but once you are familiar with the general pattern recursive functions are simple to write and more powerful than `fold` operations.

If you are working on large collections, this version is more efficient because it is `O(n)`:

```
def distinctPrefix[T](ourSeq: Seq[T]): List[T] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(rem: List[T], found: Set[T], res: List[T]): List[T] = 
    rem match {
      case hd::tail if !found.contains(hd) =>
        loop(tail, found + hd, hd +: res)
      case _ =>
        res.reverse
    }

  loop(ourSeq.toList, Set.empty, Nil)
}
```

---

This version works with any `Seq` and there are other options using `Iterator` etc. as described in the comments. You would need to be more specific about the type of the collection in order to create an optimised algorithm.

```
def uniquePrefix[T](ourSeq: Seq[T]): List[T] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(rem: Seq[T], res: List[T]): List[T] = 
    rem.take(1) match {
      case Seq(hd) if !res.contains(hd) =>
        loop(rem.drop(1), res :+ hd)
      case _ =>
        res
    }

  loop(ourSeq, Nil)
}
```

Comment: `hd::tai` will only work for **Lists** but yu accept **Seq**. So either use **List** directly _(which I really do not understand why people don't do that because they always assume the **Seq** will be a **List**)_. Or use the appropriate `+:` extractor that works for all **Seq** _(but will be really slow in everything that is not a **List**, so then again why not just using **List**)_. Another option would be to rewrite `loop` to work in terms of an **Iterator** using `nextOption()` which will work and be efficient for all **Seqs**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That's a fair point, I will edit. Your other suggestions are good, but I was keeping it simple for the OP because the main point was to use a recursive routine rather than `foldLeft`.

Answer (score -1):

Another option you have, is to use the function [`inits`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#inits:Iterator%5BC%5D):

```
ourSeq.inits.dropWhile(curr => curr.distinct.size != curr.size).next()
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/VycId8ukTP2heh7gApLr6Q).